# Is it possible to pass multiple side inputs in apache beam Java

Tags: apache-beam

I am curious to know if it's possible to pass multiple side-inputs in apache beam.

For example, I have a customer dataset, where I have zipcode, and city -– these two columns will be used to do a lookup with postcode table to find state for zipcode lookup and country name from city lookup.

Is it possible to do in a single pardo, where .withsideInputs will have two pcollections, zipcode and city? Or do I need to do in two steps?

Comment: try preparing a dictionary like {'zip_code':[],'city':[]} and pass it as side-input

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, just use [ParDo.SingleOutput.withSideInputs(Iterable)](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.35.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/ParDo.SingleOutput.html#withSideInputs-java.lang.Iterable-) or [ParDo.SingleOutput.withSideInputs(Map)](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.35.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/ParDo.SingleOutput.html#withSideInputs-java.util.Map-) for that.

Comment: Thank you Alexey. I will check these. And if you could give an example, if you have it, that would be really great.